# Can a known recipient of sending via sending stones conceal their identity?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, telepathy

A character has discovered one of a pair of *sending stones* in a D&D 5e game. They can use the stone to cast *sending*, with the target being the holder of the other stone. The person holding the other stone, who we'll call the "recipient", is in fact someone that the character knows, but they are unaware that it is the recipient who holds the other stone, and the recipient does not *want* them to know.

Can the recipient reply to the *sending* while concealing their identity from the character?

The question of the **caster** of *sending* concealing their identity has already been addressed in [Is there any way to fake/conceal your identity when casting Sending?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136267/is-there-any-way-to-fake-conceal-your-identity-when-casting-sending), and the caster cannot conceal their identity because *sending* says:

> You send a short message of twenty-five words or less **to a creature with which you are familiar.** The creature hears the message in its mind, **recognizes you as the sender if it knows you**, and can answer in a like manner immediately.

This does not address whether the recipient can conceal their identity, but this is because the caster of *sending* must be familiar with the recipient in order to cast the spell. It's therefore reasonable to assume that the recipient's "reply", which is sent "in a like manner", will mean that the caster will recognise the identity of the recipient, because the caster knows the recipient, and because the caster knows who they targeted with the spell.

However, *sending stones* bypass this familiarity requirement:

> While you touch one stone, you can use an action to cast the sending spell from it. The target is the bearer of the other stone.

There is no indication here that the user of a *sending stone* must be familiar with the recipient, who holds the matching stone. (And such a requirement would make *sending stones* considerably less useful! So I think it's reasonable to assume that the user of a stone is not required to know the holder of the other stone.)

However, in the situation I'm describing, the "caster" *is* familiar with the recipient, but the recipient does not want them to *know* who the recipient is.

Obviously, the recipient can refuse to respond. However, it's a lot more fun if the recipient can respond, while concealing their identity. This leads us to the question:
**Is there a way for a known recipient of *sending* cast via *sending stones* to conceal their identity?**

Use of additional magical items or spells by the recipient (such as the *ring of mind shielding* suggested in an answer to the linked question) is acceptable in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You don't know the target if you use *Sending Stones*

Since nothing in the spell *Sending* actually tells you who you are targeting (since it assumes you already know), and nothing in the magic items gives you the knowledge of who holds the other stone, by RAW, you don't gain any special information on who's in possession of the other stone.

I believe the phrase "in a like manner" is only referencing the means of communication, or specifically, a message of 25 words or less, that you hear in your mind.

Comment: I think the primary concern is that "in a like manner" for the response message also carries the property "recognizes you as the sender if it knows you". It would be good if you could address this.

Comment: Agreed with @ThomasMarkov.

Comment: Upvoted response is wrong.

100% agree "in a like manner" has to apply to the whole to both the SENDING of the reply and the RECEIVING of the reply, in a "like manner".

RAW, and RAI, impersonation is bidirectionally disallowed if you know the other end. I agree it could be worded better, but I believe this is 100% not only the intention of what it says, but what it actually says.

"like manner" has to apply not only to how I send it (25 words or less), but how it is received (the recipient recognizes me if they know me). The ONLY part that is dropped is the targeting requirement.